# How to get like bar to fill based on percentage of likes and dislikes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to re-create the youtube like/dislike bar which is filled with 2 different colors representing the number of likes and dislikes that compare each other and fill the color accordingly. So I have my `Product` model that you can like or dislike:

```
.vote-bar
  .bar
    .likes{style: "width: #{@product.get_likes.size}%"}
    .dislikes{style: "width: #{@product.get_dislikes.size}%"}
```

I'm using the [Acts As Votable gem](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) that gives me the amount of likes and dislikes a product has. I'm having trouble with how to get the percentage of each based on 100%. So, if I have 1 Like it should fill the whole bar and if I have 0 dislikes it should fill nothing. Another example would be 2% likes = 2% of the bar and 3% dislikes = 3% of the bar. Both divs should only be able to equal 100% in total together though. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the percentage, you'll want to divide each value by the total number of votes. You could add those methods to the Product model:

```
class Product
  def percentage_likes
    self.get_likes.size.to_f / self.votes_for.size * 100
  end

  def percentage_dislikes
    self.get_dislikes.size.to_f / self.votes_for.size * 100
  end
end
```

Notice that I've casted the likes and dislikes sizes to a float, because division of an integer by an integer will return yet another integer. Additionally, I've multiplied by 100, so that the fraction will be converted to a percentage.

Your view will then look like this:

```
.vote-bar
  .bar
    .likes{style: "width: #{@product.percentage_likes}%"}
    .dislikes{style: "width: #{@product.percentage_dislikes}%"}
```

You may have to do some extra CSS manipulation to float the .likes and .dislikes div, so that they appear side-by-side.